# how to detect malicious activity from my server

Tags: network-monitoring, malicious

I'm using a linode virtual server.
My machine is Ubuntu 10.04.

I got a ticket from Linode that they detected malicous activity coming from my server.

> "We have detected your system with an IP of, , scanning
>   a client we monitor. This was not a short attack but a prolonged scan
>   and/or probe that was designed to find and intrude into the target
>   network."

Now I'm hosting on linode to test an application, I have no idea how to manage and secure a server.

Please can someone give me some lead on how i should investigate the issue and how to solve it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server has been compromised then you should rebuild it from scratch, rather than waste too much time investigating how it was cracked. This may be easier on a virtual server.

Install both chkrootkit and rkhunter, and run them regularly as cron jobs.

Then google `harden ubuntu`

Also consider restricting access to your own ip address or subnet.

Comment: thank you. any more advice on how to prevent this in the future ?

Comment: No, there is a lot of material out there written by experts. But before concluding the worst, you might just ask your colleagues if they have run a port scan or used nmap. That might trigger the warning you have received.